# Is there an Excel function to copy text and color of a cell?

Tags: excel, function, automation

[Reference for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cc71.jpg)

I am looking for another way than VBA to automate color and text of cells from existing ones.
Copying text can be easily done by writing `=A1` in C2 and `=A2` in D2.

Is there an excel function that copies 'Yr2019' with yellow fill to C2 and 'Yr2020' with green fill to D2?

Comment: Not without VBA (or some other programming language or 3rd party tool)

Comment: You might do this with Conditional Formatting.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by Variatus, you might use conditional formatting, as in following example (sorry for the Dutch):

[image: Excel screenshot]

I've used conditional formatting for the entire worksheet.
In cells C2 and D2, I've put the formulas `=A1` and `=A2`, as you can see in the formulatext cells underneath.